# The kubernetes binary installation reported an error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The binary installation of Kubernetes 1.18 is in the order of：`etcd->apiserver->kubctl`，When using `kubectl`, the cluster information and user information are configured as follows:

```
[root@master-01 ~]# ll ~/.kube/config
-rw------- 1 root root 6257 Apr 20 22:49 /root/.kube/config
[root@master-01 ~]#
```

However, an error is still reported when using kubctl：

```
[root@master-01 ~]# kubectl get ns
error: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
[root@master-01 ~]#
```

Ask which can help look, thank you!

Comment: Hi, by default, kubectl will try to find the config file in `$HOME/.kube/config` or wherever the environment variable `KUBECONFIG` points to, maybe that variable is pointing somewhere else?

Comment: I'm going to reinstall it to see if I have the same problem